# How to assign an array to variable in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function with a reference parameter.  The function populates the reference with an array.  When it returns I test the reference value with a `print_r()`.  It's successful.  But when I try and assign it to another var as in,

```
$_SESSION['allvats'] = $ref_all_vats;
```

I get an empty session var.  How do I assign this?  I've tried declaring the reference as an array before invoking the function and also assigning to sessions as

```
$_SESSION['allvats'][] = $ref_all_vats;
```

Thank you.

Edit.

Session is running.  Other SESSION vars populate.  Here is the code bit:

```
    if(buildMetalArrayNsp($process_id, $ref_all_vats)) {
       writeDataToFile("vats " . print_r($ref_all_vats, true), __FILE__, __LINE__);
       $_SESSION['allvats'] = $ref_all_vats;
    }
```

Here is the session code:

```
$lifetime= 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;  // 30 days
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

Comment: Show us more code.

Comment: "empty session var"? Where? when? In another script? did you remember to `session_start()` in both scripts?

Comment: If your array is in `$ref_all_vats` already, then you have already assigned it to a variable; your problem isn't that; but one line isn;t really enough code to identify what it might be

Comment: Session if running.  Other SESSION vars are populating.  Here's the code bit:

Comment: Do you have PHP error logs set up correctly? Have you looked at them to see if there is an error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is fine, there is something else going wrong. Are you sure the if statement is evaluating to true? Whenever you are tracking down errors it is good to use echo or print_r quite a bit. For example:

```
echo "<pre>Above if\n";
if(buildMetalArrayNsp($process_id, $ref_all_vats)) {
   echo "In if\n";
   $_SESSION['hello'] = "world";
   $_SESSION['allvats'] = $ref_all_vats;
}
echo "Below if\n";

echo "\n-----------------------\n";
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
echo "\n-----------------------\n";
print_r($_SESSION['allvats']);
echo "\n-----------------------\n";
print_r($ref_all_vats);
echo "</pre>";
```

Of course if you are not displaying to a web page remove the `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['allvats'] = $ref_all_vats;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($firstVar, $secondVar) = explode(' ', 'Foo Bar');
```

[list()](http://php.net/list) is what you are after.